# Lock code section in c#

Tags: c#, .net

My question may sound like many others here but it has a flavor I didn't find.

I am trying to understand the following logic

A generic object

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public static void DoSomething(Object lockObj)
    {
        lock(lockObj)
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Class A

```
internal class A
{
    private static _aLock = new Object();

    public void Do_A_Thing()
    {
        GenericClass.DoSomething(_aLock);
    }
}
```

Class B

```
internal class B
{
    private static _bLock = new Object();

    public void Do_B_Thing()
    {
        GenericClass.DoSomething(_bLock);
    }
}
```

I just hope to confirm if my explanation is correct:

If multiple threads of class "A" will attempt simultaneously access code in "genericClass" method "DoSomething", this method will be locked to all but one instance of class "A". But a single instance of class "B" will be able to proceed with execution any time. If class "B" will also have multiple instances execute, they will not interfere with class "A" locks.

Is this correct based on what you see above?

Comment: yes... though the construction seems a little frightening

Comment: Do you actually have the `;` at the end of `lock(lockObj);`? You should not. That's just like having `if (someCondition); { // do stuff }`: you're only applying the `lock` or `if` to the empty statement, indicated by the `;`, not to the code block indicated by the `{ }`.

Comment: Generally you want your lock objects to be private, so that you know no one else can be locking on them. Passing them in requires a lot of trust (and knowledge) of the caller.

Comment: @Tim S., syntax here is not important. Consider this a pseudo-code

Comment: @Niall Connaughton: My lock objects are `private`. They are also `static`. Because I want instances of same type to "play nice". But at the same time, let instances of a different type to play between them selves. The code is a pseudo. Real `GenericClass.DoSomething(_aLock)` will be more like `GenericClass.DoSomething(key, data, _aLock);`. Each different type will have its key :o))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your description sounds correct. It is perhaps a little unusual to pass the lock object *in*, but it'll work fine. The only change I would suggest is to make the `static` fields `readonly` so you can't accidentally change the value to a different `object` reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. The locks in `A` and the locks in `B` are completely unaware of each other. The code will only be blocked when there is another thread locking it with the same object as identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusion is correct but it is not a good practice to pass locked object around. I suggest to put the `lock` inside class A and B respectively.

I suggest to write:

```
internal class A
{
    private static readonly _aLock = new Object();

    public void Do_A_Thing()
    {
        lock (_aLock)
        {
            GenericClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have a specific reason to put the lock in another class? Maybe you can solve your problem in a different way?

Also keep in mind that in some conditions, maybe it is not your case, you can have a deadlock if class A and B call each other (A->B->A).

Comment: What you've suggested is a typical situation which I used hundreds of times. Right now the problem is that I want generic class to be a.. generic. It should store and retrieve some caches demanded by some objects. But each object has it own cache. And I want no more than one instance of each type to retrieve or store data. One solution would be is to inherit base object with caching capability. But right now this is impossible. Looks like my thinking is confirmed.

Comment: Is it `GenericClass<T>`, and would the lock object be keyed by `T`? Because then, you could declare `private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();` in `GenericClass<T>`, which gives you a different lock object for each `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using generics, then something like

```
public class MyGadget<T>
{
  static readonly SyncRoot = new object() ;

  public T SynchronizedMethod()
  {
     lock ( SyncRoot )
     {
        SynchronizedMethodGuts() ;
     }
  }

}
```

should do what you want because `MyGadget<Foo>` and `MyGadget<Bar>` are **different classes**: they each have their own, different `SyncRoot` field.

Comment: This is interesting idea and might even work in my situation. The difference is, my "generic" only knows how to perform certain operations, no instance required. Here I need an instance. I just think, this is overkill for me and not true reason .Net generics were made for.