# C# multiple processes await static property

Tags: c#, async-await

I have several entry points in my code that all need the value of a static property at startup. Or it could be a function if needed. The part I am stuck on is that they will all call this function at approximately the same time and I only want the code to execute once. It is a call to a web service and the result will indicate a state that all of the callers need. So how do I get multiple processes to wait on the result for a single function called. I don't know how do an await from multiple locations in the code. Can you do this?

Comment: See sync lock https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992965/lock-code-section-in-c-sharp

Comment: That is for multiple processes locking independent resources. I have a shared resource (static value in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Your are allowed to `await` the same `Task` infinitely often. Example:

```
public static readonly Task<int> MyValue = GetMyValue();

private static async Task<int> GetMyValue()
{
    return await GetItFromWherever();
}
```

And then whenever you need it:

```
int myValue = await MyValue;
```

All callers will await until it's made available, then they'll continue when it's obtained. After that, this line will always run synchronously and use the already-obtained value.

Also check `Lazy<T>` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)).